# Hover an element and change another element

Tags: css

When I hover a **text field**, I want the font color of the **submit field** to become red.

I tried the operators `>`, `+` and `~` but none of them works.

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/p0zxctet/

Comment: .search-field:hover{color: red;} works fine, or do you mean the placeholder text?

Answer (score 1):

I just came back through my stack overflow and saw this hasn't been answered sufficiently yet. Here is my solution utilizing jQuery to get the effect you were looking for:

The HTML

```
<input type="text" id="textField" placeholder="Hover Here"/>
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" />
```

The jQuery

```
$("#textField").hover(function(){
    $("#submitBtn").css({"color":"red"});
});
$("#textField").mouseout(function() {
    $("#submitBtn").css({"color":"black"});
});
```

Here is the fiddle showing this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/z9czoedp/

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was going to ask how to change the font color of the submit field, not the text field. I have edited the question above.

Comment: You may need to go with a javascript / jquery solution to this. The way it is structured currently, you would need to target a cousin and there isn't really a good way to select cousin elements running down the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

try to use **:hover Selector**

```
.form-control.search-field:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

---

### 5-28 added

Do you mean when you hover the input, the submit button change its color to red?

I think css cannot do that. You need to use javascript, like:

```
document.querySelector("#db-search").onmouseover = function(){
    document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").style.color = "red"
}
document.querySelector("#db-search").onmouseout = function(){
    document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").style.removeProperty("color")
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was going to ask how to change the font color of the submit field, not the search field. I have edited the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider browser prefixes as well.

```
input {
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #cfcfcf;
}

input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #cfcfcf;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

/*
* On hover
*/
input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder,
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #F00;
}

input:hover:-moz-placeholder,
input:focus:-moz-placeholder{ /* Firefox 18- */
     color: #F00;
}

input:hover::-moz-placeholder,
input:focus::-moz-placeholder{  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #F00;
}

input:hover:-ms-input-placeholder,
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder{  
   color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was going to ask how to change the font color of the submit field, not the search field. I have edited the question above.

Comment: Use attribute selectors,                                                       input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color:red;
}